# Is it possible (and how) to see the Python source code for the package that is installed with 'pip install package-name'?

Tags: python, pip

Is it possible (and how) to see the Python source code for the package that is installed with `'pip install package-name'`? I have found wheels file, but it is in compiled format. Installation messages are also talking about building and installing, so, I guess, that only compiled code is available on my computer now?

Comment: Have you tried `from inspect import getsource; import package-name; print(getsource(package-name))`?

Answer (score 7):

Run `pip show --files package-name`. See the full paths to the files. View `*.py` files.

There are some modules and packages written in C or C++ — you cannot see their sources after installation, you have to find out their source code. Start looking for `package-name` at [PyPI](https://pypi.org/).

> wheels file … in compiled format

No, it's not. It's a zip archive. You can unzip it. Probably you can click or double-click on it in your file manager — most file managers recognize zip archives and show their content.